# MySQLi isn't fetching whole Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Currently I have this code in my website... It is supposed to fetch the whole Table but I have a problem actually... It fetch it all, except Line 1...

```
<?php
    $venue = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM Venues');
    $venueRow = mysqli_fetch_array($venue);
    while($venueRow = mysqli_fetch_array($venue)) {
        echo $venueRow['NameVenue'];
    }
?>
```

Is there a mistake I did?

Comment: You're fetching the first row before you start your `while` loop, and then overwriting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$venueRow = mysqli_fetch_array($venue);             # fetch  row 1
while($venueRow = mysqli_fetch_array($venue)) {     # fetch  row 2, 3, ...
    echo $venueRow['NameVenue'];                    # output row 2, 3, ...
}
```

Because you're calling "fetch" twice before you start processing each row.

Get rid of the first one.